# SyntaxError: Unexpected token: < in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Am new to Google App Script.

Am trying to import JSON into Google Sheet to get the values. When I give `=ImportJSON("http://cloud.anicuragroup-mail.com/testcon?tskey=13689&metric=all")` in the cell it is throwing me syntax error

Whereas almost similar JSON with different URL - `=ImportJSON("http://cloud.mail.wefox.com/param-script?tskey=48083&metric=all")` it is accepting

```js
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

Here is the link i used for import JSON - https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164
since am new to App Script.

Please help!

Comment: I saved the function which is present in Github link as ImportJSON.gs and in that file one of the function is ImportJSON which am calling in google sheet. Please let me know if this is a wrong way.

Comment: I've included `ImportJSON` in my project and run your formulae; your first gives me `400 Bad Request` rather than `Unexpected token: <` as you are finding. What information are you trying to receive? Going to `http://cloud.anicuragroup-mail.com` gives me `403`.

Comment: Probably you are trying to parse a string that is not JSON (i.e., an html error page) as JSON.

Comment: Correct @tehhowch it has HTML with JSON thats why am getting the error. Now its fine. Thanks !